# TextView cutting Right and Left Side

Tags: android, xml, layout

I am using expandable list view in one of my application. All is fine but in child view text is getting cut in right and left side looking like below image. If I set margin both side its still getting cut.

[image]

My XML is like below

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_listchild"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="10dp"
        android:background="@color/grey_200"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is this the child item of a `ListView`? If yes please show the xml of the activity that contains the `ListView`.

Comment: post code for activity where list is used

Comment: android:singleLine="false" and add gravity=left or right,padding 10dp add this in your xml